# Allowing only certain ip traffic to server using Ansible

Tags: ansible, iptables, ansible-2.x

I am using Ansible to configure my several web servers. I want to restrict all traffic coming to those servers except some hosts. Actually, i want that these servers will only be accessed by some hosts only.

Answer (score 1):

First figure out how to configure such a firewall on your system without Ansible. Then use Ansible to apply that configuration to a host.

I use package iptables-persistent on Debian 9, and use Ansible templating to manage /etc/iptables/rules.v4